# change prototype of a custom element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

If I create a custom element as follows

```
document.register('bar-foo', { prototype: { .... } }); // or document.registerElement
```

Now, after this I would like to add something the the prototype of that element.

For example, I can do this with the 'div' element:

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.bar = function() {};
document.createElement('div').bar();
```

How would I do that with my custom element 'bar-foo' ?

Comment: What is document.register? Never heard of it, and there seems to be nothing about it on MDN.

Comment: @bjb568 Just found this, look at section 5.5: http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/explainer/#defining-a-custom-element

Comment: thanks a lot, that is exactly what I needed. Your suggestion below will work too, but this one is better!

Comment: @Scott Well, do any browsers support it?

Comment: @bjb568 I'm not the one who came up with the question; I'm just googling.  Html5rocks says Chrome 31 has decent support, and Chrome 27+ and Firefox 23+ have some kind of support, and that there are polyfills otherwise: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: in Chrome, if you enable experimental javascript and experimental Web Platform features it works like a charm :) Also things like ShadowDOM and CSS Regions!!

Answer (score 2):

I implemented Custom Elements in Chrome so I'm familiar with this. (FWIW `document.register` has been renamed `document.registerElement`.)

To add something to a Custom Element's prototype later, you first need a reference to the prototype object.

In your question, you access the prototype via the constructor for DIV, `HTMLDivElement.prototype`. You can use a similar pattern in Custom Elements. A Custom Element's constructor is returned from registerElement. By saving a reference to it you can use it to access the prototype later:

```
BarFoo = document.registerElement('bar-foo', ...);

// later
BarFoo.prototype.foo = ...
```

(You can also use the returned object, which the spec calls the *generated constructor* to create elements using `new BarFoo()`.)

It makes sense to save the reference on the global object (the window) because this is how built in elements like HTMLDivElement work, although you don't have to do that.

In developing the spec, we considered making setting up a reference to this constructor on window automatic, but decided less magic and less name pollution was better. We also considered adding an object that you could pass a tag name and get back the right constructor. We wanted to make that work for built in elements as well as Custom Elements. Unfortunately that proposal didn't survive long the standards discussion lists.

There are other ways to do what you want. For example, instead of saving a reference to the generated constructor, you could save a reference to the prototype directly. Alternatively, if you have an instance of the Custom Element, you could use `Object.getPrototypeOf(elem)` or `elem.__proto__` to get the prototype object.

HTH!

Comment: This may have previously been correct, but it is no longer correct. platform.js for IE10 does not work unless registerElement is called on a modified prototype; this also does not work for firefox or chrome (but without errors).

Comment: The current version of platform.js doesn't support modifying the prototype of the value returned from registerElement(). I have no idea if this was different in the past, but what you've suggested above (var foo = docuement.registerElement(...); foo.prototype.bar = function() { ... }) only works in chrome. For cross browser support (the point of platform.js... :P) you have to modify the prototype *before* calling registerElement()

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this won't work at all unless you're using [platform.js](https://github.com/Polymer/platform), but if you are, you must bind the custom api *before* calling registerElement.

```
var prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
prototype.createdCallback = function() {
  ...
};
prototype.mycall = function() {
  console.log(this.shadowRoot.innerHTML);
};
document.registerElement('my-type', { prototype: prototype });
```

You will then be able to do this:

```
<my-type>100</my-type>
<script>
  document.getElementById('foo').mycall();
</script>
```

Notice two things:

1) As per https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.HtmlDocument#id_registerElement, the registerElement call doesn't not return a value. Platform.js is compliant with this. Don't use the return value if there is one (eg. on chrome).

2) As of platform.js 0.4.0 some browsers support calling registerElement and *then* retrospectively adding calls to the prototype. This is notably *not supported* for IE10.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found much on `register`, and found little on `registerElement`, but if it follows the rest of JavaScript's prototypal inheritance, you should be able to save the object that gives the prototype and modify it later, e.g.:

```
var saveMe = {};
document.register('bar-foo', saveMe);
saveMe.prototype = {
    // ...
}
```